# Упростить конструктор в PHP (передаётся много переменных)

Tags: style-guide, code-style, php

Есть ли возможность упростить:

```
class SomeClass {
  private $a;
  private $b;
  private $c;
  private $d;
  private $e;

  public function __construct($a, $b, $c, $d, $e) {
    $this->a = $a;
    $this->b = $b;
    $this->c = $c;
    $this->d = $d;
    $this->e = $e;
  }
}
```

Этот код рабочий. Нет ли здесь возможности воспользоваться foreach()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Меня заводят грязные хаки. Аргументы передаются в порядке их определения в классе и точно сответсвуют количеству свойств.

```
<?php
class SomeClass {
  private $a;
  private $b;
  private $c;
  private $d;
  private $e;

  public function __construct() {
    var_dump($this);
    if(count(func_get_args()) != count(get_class_vars( __CLASS__))){
        die("error");
    }
    $i=0;
    foreach(func_get_args() as $arg){
        $keys = array_keys(get_class_vars(__CLASS__));
        $key = $keys[$i];
        $this->$key = func_get_args()[$i];
        $i++;
    }
    var_dump($this);
  }
}

$class = new SomeClass(1,2,3,4,5);

?>
```

Вывод:

```
object(SomeClass)[1]
  private 'a' => null
  private 'b' => null
  private 'c' => null
  private 'd' => null
  private 'e' => null

object(SomeClass)[1]
  private 'a' => int 1
  private 'b' => int 2
  private 'c' => int 3
  private 'd' => int 4
  private 'e' => int 5
```

Comment: Чудо. И вот только теперь до меня доходит, что в итоге получается прикольный, но трудный в поддержке код. Разве что детально закомментировать порядок следования переменных.

Comment: @Khvorostin, можно применять только к определённой видимости, например есть get_class_vars для private отдельно. Можно извращаться много, но я могу ещё вариантик подкинуть позже.

Comment: @Khvorostin,
Правда нотайсы летят только здравствуй

    <?php
    class SomeClass {
      private $a;
      private $b;
      private $c;
      private $d;
      private $e;
    
      public function __construct() {
     var_dump($this);
     if(count(func_get_args()) != count(get_class_vars( __CLASS__))){
      die("error");
     }
     foreach(func_get_args() as $arg){
      $key = $arg[0];
      $this->$key = $arg[1];
     }
     var_dump($this);
      }
    }
    
    $class = new SomeClass([a,1],[d,2],[c,3],[b,4],[e,5]);
    
    ?>

Comment: @Khvorostin,

    object(SomeClass)[1]
      private 'a' => null
      private 'b' => null
      private 'c' => null
      private 'd' => null
      private 'e' => null

    object(SomeClass)[1]
      private 'a' => int 1
      private 'b' => int 4
      private 'c' => int 3
      private 'd' => int 2
      private 'e' => int 5

Answer (score 5):

Во всяких умных книгах по ООП пишут что дабы конструктор выглядел читабельно в нем должно присутствовать не более семи параметров, а проблему рекомендуют решать с помощью передачи в качестве параметров структур.
то есть

```
public A(a, b, c, ..., z)
=>
public A(someStructure1, someStructure2)
```

где
someStructure содержит какие то переменные

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что под структурами понимаются экземпляры объектов или массивы?

Comment: По структурами понимается
struct
class,
array - если у вас однотипные переменные

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот как-то так сделать:

```
class SomeClass {
  private $a;
  private $b;
  private $c;
  private $d;
  private $e;

  public function __construct() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    if (count($args) < _нужное_количество_аргументов_) {
        throw new Exception('Маловато аргументов у конструктора');   
    }  
    $this->a = $args[0];
    $this->b = $args[1];
    $this->c = $args[2];
    $this->d = $args[3];
    $this->e = $args[4];
  }
}
```